# Laravel Filamentphp 3.0: Relation Column

Tags: filamentphp

I have a problem with my Laravel filaments Relation in the "backend" interface. The column with my Relation isn't shown.

I have a simple model with a Profilisocial and Users. The edit is working and updating the Database as expected, but I cannot get it to list it on index page of the Filament backend.

I have following in my ProfilisocialResource.php

According to documentation for filamentphp version  3.x, this should be how it done:
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/tables/columns/relationships#displaying-data-from-relationships
it's the same code for filamentphp version 2.x
https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/tables/columns/relationships

```
    public static function table(Table $table): Table
{
    return $table
        ->columns([
            TextColumn::make('id')->sortable(),
            TextColumn::make('myusers.email'), <--- HERE THE NOT WORKING CODE
        ])
        ->filters([
            //
        ])
        ->actions([
            Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
        ])
        ->bulkActions([
            Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
        ]);
}
```

my Profilisocial.php model has the relation:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class Profilisocial extends Model
{
    public $table = 'profilisocial';
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'facebook',
        'twitter',
        'linkedin',
        'users_ID',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    public function myusers(): BelongsTo{
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

but the email is not displayed as you can see in the screenshot, why? can anybody help me please?
[image]

Comment: instead of<br/>
<code>TextColumn::make('myusers.email')</code>
i also try <br/>
<code>TextColumn::make('myusers.last_name')</code>
but without success
in my database, the table users has both column email and last_name populated
There are not errors in my laravel lof file

Comment: I believe there is an issue with the relationship, you would need to add the foreign key to the belong To relationship

Answer (score 1):

In your model's relationship you must define foreginID key:

```
    public function nameOfRelationship(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ParentOfRelationship::class, 'parentID');
    }
```

Example Filament/Models/Street.php:

```
...
public function city(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(City::class, 'cities_id');
    }
...
```

Now you can use "dot notation":

```
Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('city.name')
```

or

```
 Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('city.zip_code')
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

> hi, change your user relation ship to

```
public function myusers(): BelongsTo{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'users_ID', 'id');
}
```